# Sum up org-mode column depending on first column value

Tags: emacs, org-mode, graphite

I have a table that has duplicate Unix time stamps in the the first column and I want to sum up the values of the second column if they have the same Unix time stamp.

```
|-----Time---| Value |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| 1420067592 |    23 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| 1420076520 |    10 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| 1420078752 |     2 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| 1420067592 |     6 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| 1420076520 |     4 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| 1420078752 |    89 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| 1420067592 |    66 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| 1420078752 |    81 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| 1420076520 |    15 |
```

The reason why I have this is I am doing multiple whisper-fetch in a code block and would like to sum up the values for the same time stamps.

Any hint how I could do this in org-mode? It would be pretty cool to produce the yearly report with Emacs :)

Comment: What is the expected output in your example? Is it a single cell, or is it a new table with all unique timestamps and their accumulated values?

Comment: Both solutions are ok for me

Answer (score 3):

I found an acceptable solution by using the produced table as input for another code block that's executing a Python snippet to sum up the results

```
#+NAME: results
|       Time | Value |
|------------+-------|
| 1420067592 |    23 |
| 1420076520 |    10 |
| 1420078752 |     2 |
| 1420067592 |     6 |
| 1420076520 |     4 |
| 1420078752 |    89 |
| 1420067592 |    66 |
| 1420078752 |    81 |
| 1420076520 |    15 |

#+begin_src python :var data=results :exports results
output = {}

for line in data:
    if output.get(line[0]):
        output[line[0]] += line[1]
    else:
        output[line[0]] = line[1]

return [[x,y] for x,y in output.items()]
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| 1420067592 |  95 |
| 1420076520 |  29 |
| 1420078752 | 172 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Orgtbl-Aggregate` package available on Melpa

```
#+name: thetimes
|       Time | Value |
|------------+-------|
| 1420067592 |    23 |
| 1420076520 |    10 |
| 1420078752 |     2 |
| 1420067592 |     6 |
| 1420076520 |     4 |
| 1420078752 |    89 |
| 1420067592 |    66 |
| 1420078752 |    81 |
| 1420076520 |    15 |

#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "thetimes" :cols "Time vsum(Value)"
|       Time | vsum(Value) |
|------------+-------------|
| 1420067592 |          95 |
| 1420076520 |          29 |
| 1420078752 |         172 |
#+END:
```